# How do we update layout details in template's standard values without affecting existing pages?

Tags: powershell

I have a situation where I need to set correct controls in layout- presentation details for my template standard values, without affecting the existing pages which uses the template.  We have manually set the correct controls in those existing pages. Can I achieve this using powershell script?

Any guidance would be helpful.

Comment: Did this answer your question? https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/22828/updating-a-field-standard-value-for-page-data-template-without-affecting-the-fie

Comment: a less ideal solution, if you want to leave all the existing pages as is, is to duplicate the page template and make changes to the new page template, then update the branch templates to use the new page template